# Formatting a month string is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to create month strings that look like "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"... Here is my code:

```
- (NSString *)getMonthNameString:(int)monthNumber {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];

    NSArray *monthNames = [formatter standaloneMonthSymbols];
    NSString *monthName;

    if (monthNumber > 0) {
        return monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
    }      

    return monthNames[1];
}
```

So if the month number is 1, I'm expecting the code to provide month name as "Jan" and if it is 2, it has to provide month name as "Feb" and so on. But the problem is that even though I have set the format as `MMM`, it is still creating month names of type "January", "February" etc instead of "Jan","Feb" etc. How do I sort this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
-(NSString*)getMonthNameString:(int)monthNumber
{
    NSDateFormatter *formate = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formate setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
    NSArray *monthNames = [formate shortMonthSymbols];
    NSString *monthName;
    if (monthNumber > 0)
    {
        monthName = [monthNames objectAtIndex:(monthNumber - 1)];

    }

    return monthName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's usually not what a NSDateFormatter is for - it is for converting real dates, and not just month numbers.

If you want to stick with it, I suggest

```
-(NSString*)getMonthNameString:(int)monthNumber {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    return formatter.shortMonthSymbols[monthNumber-1];
}
```

I see no benefit in the extra check for > 0. This just masks programming errors. You might want to add an assertion to catch that during development. (Why should an invalid number return January anyway?)

Creating formatters is expensive, though - you might want to reuse the same instance over and over again.

Or just access an array directly, i.e.

```
-(NSString*)getMonthNameString:(int)monthNumber {
    return @[@"Jan", @"Feb", ...][monthNumber-1]; // write up to December of course
}
```

Comment: he pass month number  " Zero (0) whats happening " @Eiko

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P Maybe read my answer, I explicitly mention that case. And it's trivial to add a border check - which maybe should include cases for > 12 as well. In any case, it does not address his question: **short names**.

Answer (score 0):

*standaloneMonthSymbols* is a property of NSDateFormatter. I don't think it uses the *dateFormat* you've set. Try using *shortStandaloneMonthSymbols* property instead (or *veryShortStandaloneMonthSymbols* if you just need one letter symbol).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
-(NSString*)getMonthNameString:(int)monthNumber
{
    NSDateFormatter *formate = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formate setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [formate setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
    NSArray *monthNames = [formate standaloneMonthSymbols];
    NSString *monthName;
    if (monthNumber > 0)
    {
        monthName = [monthNames objectAtIndex:(monthNumber - 1)];

    }

    return monthName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tahavath is right. Specifically, you want to use the shortStandaloneMonthSymbols property to get it to print "Jan" or "Feb" etc.

Answer (score -1):

Check your code @Karuppu MGR

```
-(NSString*)getMonthNameString:(int)monthNumber
{
   NSDateFormatter *formate = [NSDateFormatter new];
   [formate setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
   NSArray *monthNames = [formate standaloneMonthSymbols];
   NSString *monthName;
     if (monthNumber > 0 && monthNumber<13)
     {
       monthName = [monthNames objectAtIndex:(monthNumber - 1)];
       // your process is right but , here you have attached "return value " so every time return the monthNames array value.


     }
     return monthName;  // if you pass zero or greathan  twelve monthName return nil value
  }
```

Comment: no, his code was correct in this regard. He just returned the desired value.

Comment: are you check this code ? how you are downvote me? @Eiko

Comment: you can try this code to check it in xcode. i have check it and post the answer. @Eiko

Comment: All he does in the "if" branch is setting the monthName and returning it directly. Your change does nothing but remove that direct return. It also changes the logic by returning a completely uninitialized variable for monthNumber == 0. But the worst part is, you do not address his question at all: "short month names". So I think it is absolutely inappropriate as an answer - and you should probably just delete it.

Comment: monthNames Array contains whole month. so we need check the monthNumber from method to get the required month. this also a type of answer.

Comment: at the same time i am same what is problem we are face in the code. this the main think the developer understand. so i am not able to delete the answer.@Eiko

Comment: I suggest you run his original method, your method, and either mine or ar000bin method side by side. You will see that your method is no improvement whatsoever.

Comment: he using shortMoth return thats all. same mistake  he also doing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115318/discussion-between-harikrishnan-p-and-eiko).